# Is the goodness of fit test in JMP the Hosmer-Lemeshow goodness of fit test?

Tags: logistic, diagnostic, jmp, hosmer-lemeshow-test

I'm working with an organization that is using JMP in their analysis, and I can't tell from the description in [JMP's help files](http://www.jmp.com/support/help/The_Logistic_Fit_Report.shtml#65559) if the test for goodness of fit in their logistic regression is the Hosmer-Lemeshow test. If it makes a difference, my data set has only one predictor variable, so we aren't considering complex models.

> The next questions that JMP addresses are whether there is enough
>   information using the variables in the current model or whether more
>   complex terms need to be added. The Lack of Fit test, sometimes called
>   a Goodness of Fit test, provides this information. It calculates a
>   pure-error negative log-likelihood by constructing categories for
>   every combination of the regressor values in the data (Saturated line
>   in the Lack Of Fit table), and it tests whether this log-likelihood is
>   significantly better than the Fitted model.
>
> The Saturated degrees of freedom is m–1, where m is the number of
>   unique populations. The Fitted degrees of freedom is the number of
>   parameters not including the intercept. For the Ingots example, these
>   are 18 and 2 DF, respectively. The Lack of Fit DF is the difference
>   between the Saturated and Fitted models, in this case 18–2=16.
>
> The Lack of Fit table lists the negative log-likelihood for error due
>   to Lack of Fit, error in a Saturated model (pure error), and the total
>   error in the Fitted model. Chi-square statistics test for lack of fit.

(I'm an engineer, not a statistician, the saturated line parts are confusing me).

Comment: Hosmer-Lemeshow is considered obsolete:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/273966/logistic-regression-with-poor-goodness-of-fit-hosmer-lemeshow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the likelihood ratio goodness-of-fit test for contingency tables. The [saturated model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/283/) has a parameter for every cell ("combination of regressor values")  so it fits the data as well as possible, & you're testing to see if that's significantly better than your model. But you need a few counts in each cell for the test statistic (the [deviance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deviance_%28statistics%29)) to have roughly a chi-square distribution, so that ought to be mentioned somewhere—the approximation's not going to be much use when you have a continuous regressor.

If the point is to assess "whether there is enough information using the variables in the current model or whether more complex terms need to be added", a likelihood-ratio test between the current model & one with those more complex terms included will be more relevant anyway.