# How to see Simpson's paradox effect via glm in R

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, poisson-regression, simpsons-paradox

I am using the `UCBAdmissions` dataset and `glm` from `R` to check for Simpson's paradox. I am aware that with data that I have, it is easier to *visualise* the paradox, but I am trying to inspect it via a *Poisson*/*Log-linear* model too.

**My attempt**

To visualise this is easy:

```
library(broom)
ucb_tidy <- tidy(UCBAdmissions) %>% group_by(Gender, Dept) %>% mutate(prop = n/sum(n))

ggplot(ucb_tidy, aes(x=Gender, y=prop, fill = Admit)) +
    ggtitle("Acceptance Rate Split by Gender & Department") +
    facet_wrap(~ Dept, nrow = 2) +
    guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
    xlab("Gender") + ylab("% of Applicants") +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format())
```

[image]

But to check and show this with a Poisson model, I tried the following:

```
# Postulate that Gender and Admission are conditionally independent, given Dept.
cond_ind1 <- glm(n ~ (Gender + Admit) * Dept, family = poisson, data = ucb_tidy)
summary(cond_ind1)

Call:
glm(formula = n ~ (Gender + Admit) * Dept, family = poisson, 
    data = ucb_tidy)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-3.4776  -0.4144   0.0098   0.3089   2.2321  

Coefficients:
                    Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)          6.27557    0.04248 147.744  < 2e-16 ***
GenderFemale        -2.03325    0.10233 -19.870  < 2e-16 ***
AdmitRejected       -0.59346    0.06838  -8.679  < 2e-16 ***
DeptB               -0.40575    0.06770  -5.993 2.06e-09 ***
DeptC               -1.53939    0.08305 -18.536  < 2e-16 ***
DeptD               -1.32234    0.08159 -16.207  < 2e-16 ***
DeptE               -2.40277    0.11014 -21.816  < 2e-16 ***
DeptF               -3.09624    0.15756 -19.652  < 2e-16 ***
GenderFemale:DeptB  -1.07581    0.22860  -4.706 2.52e-06 ***
GenderFemale:DeptC   2.63462    0.12343  21.345  < 2e-16 ***
GenderFemale:DeptD   1.92709    0.12464  15.461  < 2e-16 ***
GenderFemale:DeptE   2.75479    0.13510  20.391  < 2e-16 ***
GenderFemale:DeptF   1.94356    0.12683  15.325  < 2e-16 ***
AdmitRejected:DeptB  0.05059    0.10968   0.461    0.645    
AdmitRejected:DeptC  1.20915    0.09726  12.432  < 2e-16 ***
AdmitRejected:DeptD  1.25833    0.10152  12.395  < 2e-16 ***
AdmitRejected:DeptE  1.68296    0.11733  14.343  < 2e-16 ***
AdmitRejected:DeptF  3.26911    0.16707  19.567  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 2650.095  on 23  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:   21.736  on  6  degrees of freedom
AIC: 216.8

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```

This, however, is not a good fit if we use `pchisq` to check for goodness of fit, and does not directly show the effect of admission via departments, for sex.

I thought of another formulation:

```
# Postulate that Gender and Admission are jointly independent of Dept (or not)
joint_ind1 <- glm(n ~ Dept + (Gender*Admit), family = poisson, data = ucb_tidy)
summary(joint_ind1)

Call:
glm(formula = n ~ Dept + (Gender * Admit), family = poisson, 
    data = ucb_tidy)

Deviance Residuals: 
     Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
-19.7226   -7.8760    0.6475    7.1298   14.7146  

Coefficients:
                           Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                 5.50922    0.04106 134.188  < 2e-16 ***
DeptB                      -0.46679    0.05274  -8.851  < 2e-16 ***
DeptC                      -0.01621    0.04649  -0.349 0.727355    
DeptD                      -0.16384    0.04832  -3.391 0.000696 ***
DeptE                      -0.46850    0.05276  -8.879  < 2e-16 ***
DeptF                      -0.26752    0.04972  -5.380 7.44e-08 ***
GenderFemale               -0.76584    0.05128 -14.933  < 2e-16 ***
AdmitRejected               0.22013    0.03879   5.675 1.38e-08 ***
GenderFemale:AdmitRejected  0.61035    0.06389   9.553  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 2650.1  on 23  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 2004.2  on 15  degrees of freedom
AIC: 2181.3

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5
```

This has an even poorer fit, and does not have the logical appeal as the conditionally independent model.

---

**My question is:**

1. How can I study Simpson's paradox via the Poisson regression model? Would you recommend another model (e.g., binomial logistic regression)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a few ideas. This answer draws on a post by [Norm Matloff](https://matloff.wordpress.com/2014/04/21/simpsons-paradox-is-back/), who fit log-linear models on the same dataset in R using `loglin()` to show how the paradox is related to the order in which the variables are considered.

First we'll load the packages and data. I'll also set up deviation contrasts to mirror the output we'd get from a traditional log-linear analysis (as in the post above), but using `glm()`.

```r
# Import Packages
library(tidyverse)

# Import data
ucb_tidy <- broom::tidy(UCBAdmissions) %>% 
  mutate_at(c("Gender", "Dept", "Admit"), as.factor)

# Specify Deviation Contrasts
contrasts(ucb_tidy$Admit) <- contrasts(ucb_tidy$Gender) <- contr.sum(2)
contrasts(ucb_tidy$Dept) <- contr.sum(6)
```

#### Poisson Regression

Now if you're interested in model fit, we can fit three nested models.

- The first will include admission by gender terms, while ignoring the effects of department.
- The second will also include department and department-admission interactions.
- The third will do the same, but also include an interaction between gender and department.

We can then use likelihood ratio tests (using the `lmtest` package) to evaluate whether these additional department-interaction terms progressively improve our model fit.

```r
library(lmtest)

# Model Building Approach
m1 <- glm(n ~ Admit + Gender + Admit:Gender, 
          data = ucb_tidy,
          family = poisson)
m2a <- update(m1, . ~ . + Dept + Admit:Dept)
m2b <- update(m2a, . ~ . + Gender:Dept)

# Test model fit using lmtest
lrtest(m1, m2a, m2b)
```

Incorporating the department as a predictor that also interacts with admissions (i.e. `m2a`) improves the model fit relative to the model ignoring the department (i.e. `m1`), $\chi^2=1014.8, p < .0001$. The model that additionally incorporates an interaction between gender and department (i.e. `m2b`) improves model fit over and above this, $\chi^2=1128.7, p < .0001$. We would therefore select `m2b` as our final model<sup>1</sup>, although you could continue on with the three-way interaction if you're feeling so bold (although [this model would be saturated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/283/)).

The 'paradox' is probably easier to understand though when you plot the model predictions. I'll use `emmeans` for this, and put the predictions on the numbers admitted scale (rather than the default log scale). The `patchwork` package just joins the two plots at the end using `+`.

```r
# Plot model predictions using emmeans and patchwork
library(emmeans)
library(patchwork)

m1_plot <- emmip(m1, Gender ~ Admit, 
                 CIs = TRUE, type = "response") + 
  labs(title = "m1 - No Department Term") + 
  theme_minimal() + ylim(c(50, 300)) +
  theme(legend.position = "none") 

m2b_plot <- emmip(m2b, Gender ~ Admit, 
                  CIs = TRUE, type = "response") + 
  labs(title = "m2b - Department Interactions") +
  theme_minimal() + ylim(c(50, 300))

m1_plot + m2b_plot
```

[image]

While fewer women were applying overall in this UCB dataset (roughly half the number of men), the model that ignores which departments they were applying to would suggest the women were rejected at a higher rate relative to the men. The model that does include the department as a predictor though, and particularly the department-gender interaction, would suggest the opposite effect (when averaging over the departments).<sup>2</sup> You can check how close the model predictions were to the raw data using `emmeans` once more:

```r
# Predictions
emmeans(m2b, ~ Dept:Admit + Dept:Gender, type = "response")

# Observed
ucb_tidy
```

#### Logistic Regression

Finally, it is indeed possible to model the proportions of people admitted by department and gender using logistic regression (rather than the raw counts, as in the poisson regression above). You'd do that like so:

```r
# Convert Data
ucb_logit <- spread(ucb_tidy, Admit, n)

# Model Building Approach
ml1 <- glm(cbind(Admitted, Rejected) ~ Gender, 
           data = ucb_logit,
           family = binomial)
ml2a <- update(ml1, . ~ . + Dept)
ml2b <- update(ml2a, . ~ . + Gender:Dept)

# Test Nested Models
lrtest(ml1, ml2a, ml2b)

# Plot Probability of Acceptance by Dept & Gender
emmip(ml2b, Gender ~ Dept, type = "response", CI = TRUE)
```

This plot shows the model can replicate the [observed proportions in the dataset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_paradox#UC_Berkeley_gender_bias) fairly well.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> This model gives us identical parameter estimates to Norm's `loglin()` results.</sup>
<sup><sup>2</sup> Note that the scales are slightly different because including department in the model 2b weights the estimates differently.</sup>

Comment: (+1) Nice illustration! P.S. Shouldn't this be `broom::tidy` instead of just `tidy`?

Comment: nice answer and good plots!

Comment: @awhug I am indebted to you for having educated me :)

I think in this use-case, it seems a logistic regression model is probably more intuitive as it lets us see difference in prob. of being admitted readily, while a poisson/log-lin model lets us see the difference only in terms of counts.
Also perhaps because a log-lin model does not directly model relationship between dependent and independent variables (instead, assuming no such distinction exists)

Comment: My pleasure @info_seeker. Yeah, the logistic model seems a little 'neater' to me in this case, just wanted to make sure to answer your original question about the poisson model. And thank you @chl -- I had assumed `broom` was loaded with the tidyverse but have just edited to be explicit now.