# What is the name of a model that is not saturated?

Tags: regression, terminology

Is there a standard way to refer to a statistical model that is not saturated?

It is for paper writing. For the moment, I am using the term "non-saturated model" but I think there must be better words options for it.

EDIT: Here I am considering A saturated model as a model which there are as many estimated parameters as data points.

Suggestions are welcome.

Ps.: I am not sure which tag is appropriate for this question.

Comment: what do you mean by *saturated*?

Comment: @Aksakal: saturated in sense that the number of parameters are equal the number of data points. I will edit my question to include that information.

Comment: Your definition is a particular, common case (or there is inconsistency across fields). A saturated model is one in which all parameters have been estimated, and no further improvement can be made by adding more variables or parameters. So a regression model with two binary categorical covariates and four parameters ($x_1,x_2,x_1 \times x_2, \mathtt{intercept}$) would be saturated but generally has fewer parameters than the number of observations if $N>4=k$.

Comment: [What is a "saturated" model?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/283/what-is-a-saturated-model)

Comment: Thanks for the contribution @dimitriy. The definition that I put in the EDIT maybe is the most precise. I took the definition in the link https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/283/what-is-a-saturated-model.  

 Nevertheless, he question is not about the definition of Saturated model, but of what the name for models that are not saturated.

Comment: I doubt there is anything other that *non-saturated*