# Am I right using this mixed effect model?

Tags: mixed-model

I'm new to mixed effect models, but I think I should use a crossed random effect model: **V ~ A + (1|B) + (1|C) + (1|D) + (1|P)**. Could you please tell me if I'm right?

I ran an experiment with 10 participants. Each participant had to complete several trials. My analyses include:

- 1 continuous dependent variable **V**.
- 5 categorical independent variables : **A** (2 categories), **B** (8 categories), **C** (2 categories), **D** (2 categories), **P** (the participant, 10 categories). The combination of these 5 variables allow to uniquely describe each trial (e.g., trial X had: A category 1, B category 6, C category 1, D category 2, P participant 10).

To note, each participant had the same number of trials with each category of the variables B, C and D, BUT the number of trials with each of the two categories of the variable A differed between participants.

I'm interested in answering the question: does A affect V? But I want to control for the potential effects B, C, D and P might have on V.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: How many total trials were there?

Comment: 16 trials per participant, 160 in total

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're describing a [*saturated* random effects model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/283/what-is-a-saturated-model). You'll need to remove at least one of the random effects. I agree that you should adjust for Participant. With so few trials per participant, you're probably better off controlling for your independent variables as fixed-effects.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Am I understanding correctly that you recommend using V ~ A + B + C + D + (1|P), or do I still need to remove one independent variable?

Comment: That should be fine